# Cannot figure out how the nested for loop runs

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I cannot figure out how the below **for loop** could yeild the below output. Specifically, the 3rd and 4th outputs does not make sense to me. How `count2` is equal 0 after it was equal 1, though in the **for loop** there is no subtraction operator?

Can you give the description of how the **for loop** runs?

the script:

```
for (int count = 0; count <=3; count++) {
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++)
                System.out.println(count2);
```

The output:

```
0

0

1

0

1

2
```

Comment: what is the value of the n here?

Comment: @KickButtowski it is actually 'count'.

Comment: For what? @WilliamPrice

Comment: @user3628602 try this code to see if you can understand it better.  for (int count = 0; count <=3; count++) {
            for (int count2 = 0; count2 < count; count2++)
                System.out.print(count2 + " ");
            System.out.println("");
     }

Comment: @user3628602 A debugger will _show you_ exactly how the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

i hope now it make more clear to you.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int count = 0 ; count <= 3 ; count++) {
        System.out.println("\ncount = " + count);
        for (int count2 = 0 ; count2 < count ; count2++)
            System.out.println("count2 = " + count2);
    }
  }
}
```

**output**

```
count = 0

count = 1
count2 = 0

count = 2
count2 = 0
count2 = 1

count = 3
count2 = 0
count2 = 1
count2 = 2
```

** **count2** loop will run `(count-1)` times only.

Comment: Only until now I know that each time the 1st loop iterate, the 2nd loop reset the value of count2. Is this also apply to other types of loop like while loop?

Comment: @user3628602 It will be good if you try yourself, debug and if still some issues ask on SOW. Everybody will help you then.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just put in Correct Order so that You can Understand it in better way...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int count = 0 ; count <= 3 ; count++) {
            System.out.println("For Count = "+count);
            for (int count2 = 0 ; count2 < count ; count2++)
                System.out.println("-->  count2 = " + count2);
            System.out.println();
        }
      }
```

**Output**

```
For Count = 0  

For Count = 1  
-->  count2 = 0

For Count = 2  
-->  count2 = 0  
-->  count2 = 1  

For Count = 3  
-->  count2 = 0  
-->  count2 = 1  
-->  count2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the comparison in the second for loop, by comparing it to the first iteration of the first loop. This is generating your sporadic code because it increments the nested for loop and checks the comparison, but for example in the first iteration, `count` is equal to 0. It discontinues the nested loop and stats the outer loop again, and also incrementing `count`. This time, your nested loop can reach one before resetting.

This is the same for every remainder loop, the nested reaches the current iteration of the outer loop and stops. The outer loop is incremented and the inner loop will start from 0 and end at the iteration of the outer loop.

My advice is to use a different value for comparison in the second for loop, unless your output is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

The second for loop reinitializes everytime the first for loop iterates.
the 1st output is the 1st iteration of the 1st forloop
the 2nd, 3rd output is from the 2nd iteration of the 1st forloop
the 4th, 5th, 6th output is from the 3rd iteration of the 1st forloop

Each iteration of the 1st forloop causes the 2nd forloop to reset to 0

Comment: Only until now I know that each time the 1st loop iterate, the 2nd loop reset the value of count2. Is this also apply to other types of loop like while loop?